# Can't see SVG images in Firefox

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, firefox

Hi,

I've posted some images in my answer:
[Separate polygons based on intersection using PostGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/83/separate-polygons-based-on-intersection-using-postgis/601#601)

The images are only visible from Google Chrome, but invisible from Firefox. This bug has been confirmed by another user in my office.

**Update:**
This might have something to do with this specific image type (SVG)? If so, perhaps the site should autoconvert these to another type, or prohibit this specific image type.

Admins - any ideas?

Adam

Answer (score 3):

This is by design from our perspective -- it's like using a .png image in early versions of Internet Explorer, before the browser supported that image format yet.

So when you link to .svg as an `<img>` just be aware you're limiting the audience, as not all browsers can render that content.

I suggest converting these to simpler `.png` image files. I've done so for the post in question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and edit! Any idea when this issue will be solved in Firefox?

Comment: Adam, its probably best to check in on the Firefox support channels directly, such as http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/. The larger problem with SVG is IE, which has no support, and likely won't until IE9 is released. Even on a tech-centric site, IE makes up a significant amount of the userbase and cannot be cast aside without affecting many users: http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_stats.asp

Answer (score 0):

It works in browsers that support SVG within an IMG tag like Chrome. Firefox needs SVG to be in an OBJECT tag. IE does not support SVG. Check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics#Support_for_SVG_in_web_browsers for reference.

Comment: That's a good technical explanation, but how do we handle this for our site visitors? Perhaps the platform should change the tags or convert the picture for other browsers.

Comment: That would be nice, but stack exchange doesn't have any local storage or processing capabilities for images. See this question (and maybe others?): http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4376/please-allow-image-uploads-directly-onto-the-site

Answer (score 0):

SVG is more like flash than an image. Support for it in browsers has always been through plugins rather than trying to use it directly as an image.

Google went off on their own on this one in Chrome and so it has been included in HTML5.  However this is not a standard yet.

So basically just don't use SVG images **yet**

As for confusion with visitors, I think it is uncommon that they will end up with an SVG image to upload unless they have made it, in which case they should know the need to make it a png for web use for the moment.

Comment: SVG has been a (neglected) standard for over a decade, and embedded SVG support in HTML5 is only part of the story.  I agree that using SVG for general web media doesn't make sense now, and likely won't for at least five-seven years.  Look at all the pink on [caniuse svg](http://caniuse.com/#cats=SVG&statuses=rec,pr,cr,wd,ietf). For a history of native browser support for SVG, see [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics#Support_for_SVG_in_web_browsers).

Comment: That chart is a little misleading in that you could always use the activex plugin in IE.  I think a lot of the problem was that Adobe couldn't decide whether it was supposed to be an alternative to Flash or a print thing, now we all see it as more of a vector image format. Since Adobe now owns Flash as well, their momentum behind SVG has fallen away somewhat and what is left has shifted focus.  So perhaps now it is freeer to be something useful.